# Does compiled C# use Reverse Polish Notation?

Tags: c#

I am interested in Reverse Polish Notation and I have read that it is used in calculations on a machine level and some languages like F# are using it while also compilers turn Infix to Postfix (Reverse Polish Notation).

However I am not sure if this is true for every compiler and more specifically C#.

Also while we are on the subject I have seen this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ha78yWRDlE which explains Postfix using Assembly code. Does Assembly code use Postfix?

I am sorry if the answer is little stupid, but I havent used machine code before so I am little bit in the dark.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what you mean. There are floating point implementations that use a stack for calculations (like x87) but it's not the only way. It's also very different what the compiler does and what the output is. So the answer may be this or that depending on what is the exact question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this C# program:

```
int x = 10;
int y = 100;
int z = 11;
int r = (x + y) * z - (y + x);
Console.WriteLine(r);
```

If compile it and then look at compiled assembly, you will see this (note that it's not assembly language but IL - intermediate language which will be compiled to native assembly language only at runtime):

```
IL_0001: ldc.i4.s     10 // x variable
IL_0003: stloc.0      // store in slot 0

IL_0004: ldc.i4.s     100 // y variable
IL_0006: stloc.1      // store in slot 1

IL_0007: ldc.i4.s     11 // z variable
IL_0009: stloc.2      // store in slot 2

IL_000a: ldloc.0      // x
IL_000b: ldloc.1      // y
IL_000c: add          // +
IL_000d: ldloc.2      // z
IL_000e: mul          // *
IL_000f: ldloc.1      // y
IL_0010: ldloc.0      // x
IL_0011: add          // +
IL_0012: sub          // -
IL_0013: stloc.3      // V_3
IL_0014: ldloc.3      // V_3
IL_0015: call         void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
IL_001b: ret
```

As you see, our infix notation was indeed kind of "turned" by C# compiler into reverse polish (postfix) notation, so

```
(x + y) * z - (y + x)
```

became

```
x y + z * y x + -
```

Comment: Note that what the JIT makes from that will look _very_ different.

Comment: Thank you, very much. Also - how can I view the compiled code?I would like to play with it  and see the generated code, but I dont know from where to view it?

Comment: @ЛуциПетков I use JetBrains dotPeek decompiler: https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/. Install it, then just drag-drop your compiled assembly and you will see decompiled C# code and in the right window ("IL Viewer") - corresponding IL. If you want to view generated native assembly code - that's more complicated. For that you need to actually run application (with WinDbg for example), because IL is compiled to assembly code only at runtime.

Comment: Jetbrains do a free tool called dotPeek that will let you see the IL and C# side by side.

Comment: @Joey I looked at JITted assembly code out of curiosity and found that it just optimized the whole thing into `Console.WriteLine(1100)` :) Makes sense.

Comment: @Evk I am sorry to bother you again, but I downloaded it and tried to open my project ReversePolishNotation with Program.cs file in it and I cant seem to find what exactly should I open. Which file I need to drag and drop exactly?

Comment: @ЛуциПетков you should compile your program first. If you use Visual Studio - build your project and then drop resulting dll\exe file to dotPeek. If you don't use Visual Studio - compile it the other way you usually do that.

Comment: @Evk I have compiled my program and it finished executing (havent closed the console) and then I went into the project folder where there is Program.cs with bin folder and obj folder. In bin folder there are 2 files. `ReversePolishNotation.exe` and `ReversePolishNotation.vshost.exe` and when I open `.vshost` file I see this http://prntscr.com/hh5usn and I cant see any .dll files generated. I must add that I have run my program with Visual Studio and it has executed and the console and Visual Studio are still open.

Comment: @ЛуциПетков close everything, then take ReversePolishNotation.exe and drop it to dotPeek (no need to execute this program). On not drop but use File > Open in dotPeek and choose ReversePolishNotation.exe.

Comment: @Evk By default it showed me the code but then I did a right click and saw "IL Code" and it all works now. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Evk: I'm actually surprised the IL compiler doesn't do constant folding. I think it used to but maybe that changed with Roslyn (considering that RyuJIT has probably better optimizations).

Comment: @Joey yes I first compiled that in debug without optimizations because thought with optimizations it will do that, but no - with optimizations produces approximately the same IL.

Answer (score 0):

Compiled C# is compiled from an *Abstract Syntax Tree* (AST).

The algorithm to create the AST essentially converts infix notation to RPN and then uses a stack based algorithm to evaluate the RPN. Ala the RPN Shunting Yard algorithm.

This code reads a `.cs` source file and parses it to create an AST.

```
StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Karl\Source\Repos\ASTEngine\ASTDemo04082018.cs");
sB = new StringBuilder(sR.ReadToEnd()); // build the tree from a sR file
CSharpSyntaxTree tree = (CSharpSyntaxTree)CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(sB.ToString());
node = tree.GetRoot();
```

This is all part of the C#/Roslyn Syntax API which includes a syntax walker class which visits the AST nodes and tokens in the correct sequence for expression evaluation.

I am in the process of designing a new kind of FPGA computer that executes C Expressions and Statements.  There will be no need to compile to a computer instruction set ISA and FPGA embedded memory blocks will be used for data and control word storage.

The design is intended for embedded/SOC rather then general purpose computing.

The source file can be compiled and debugged using Visual Studio C# before the FPGA design is started.